# Find a loop through an array and find where the value in a cell changes

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently learning VBA and am struggling to complete the most basic of tasks... I need to be able to loop through an array of integers (such as: a, a, a, a, ab, ab, ab, etc.) and when it changes from a to ab get the integer, place it in another cell, then move down the list and repeat. With the code I have written it will move through all the changes but not place them into different cells. Can someone please help me? I am including a picture of what should happen.

What should happen

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Sub StockInformationCalculator()

    'Place designations here
    Dim TickerType As String
    Dim Final As Long
    
    'Create headers for variables we need to return
    Range("I1").Value = "Ticker"
    Range("J1").Value = "Yearly Change"
    Range("K1").Value = "Percent Change"
    Range("L1").Value = "Total Stock Volume"
    Range("Q1").Value = "Ticker"
    Range("R1").Value = "Value"
    Range("O2").Value = "Greatest % Increase"
    Range("O3").Value = "Greatest % Decrease"
    Range("O4").Value = "Greatest Total Volume"
    
    
    
    'Make workbook fluid by finding last row and using that in for loop
    Final = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 
    'Create for loop to return ticker type
    For c = 2 To Final
    
        If Cells(c + 1, 1).Value <> Cells(c, 1).Value Then
        TickerType = Cells(c, 1).Value
        Cells(c, 9).Value = TickerType
    
        End If
    
    Next c
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean "place it in another cell" what are you wanting to be placed and where are you wanting it to place? Are you saying you want a list of all the different tickers in column 9 one after the other? But currently your code would put the change on the line it was found on leaving big gaps? Is that what is happening?

Comment: Every time the loop finds that my value has change (e.g. a to ab) I need my code to save the variable a then show that variable in a different location such cell I2. Yes! I want a list of all tickers in column 9, thank you! That's the best way to put it. Currently my code does a quick run through of all different tickers in one cell then lands on the very last one. Sorry if I just made things even more confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you need another variable to track the number of different tickers found which you can then use to place in another column and use that counter as the row number instead of c like you were.

You also don't need the `TickerType` as you could just equal one cell to the other. Cut out the middle man. But if you were gonna use it later then that's fine.

See if this works for you.

```
Sub StockInformationCalculator()

    'Place designations here
    Dim TickerType As String
    Dim Final As Long
    Dim TickRow As Long: TickRow = 2 'Set to starting row number you want list to populate on
    
    'Create headers for variables we need to return
    Range("I1").Value = "Ticker"
    Range("J1").Value = "Yearly Change"
    Range("K1").Value = "Percent Change"
    Range("L1").Value = "Total Stock Volume"
    Range("Q1").Value = "Ticker"
    Range("R1").Value = "Value"
    Range("O2").Value = "Greatest % Increase"
    Range("O3").Value = "Greatest % Decrease"
    Range("O4").Value = "Greatest Total Volume"
    
    
    
    'Make workbook fluid by finding last row and using that in for loop
    Final = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 
    'Create for loop to return ticker type
    For c = 2 To Final
        If Cells(c + 1, 1).Value <> Cells(c, 1).Value Then
            TickerType = Cells(c, 1).Value
            Cells(TickRow, 9).Value = TickerType
            TickRow = TickRow + 1 'Add 1 every time a different ticker is found
        End If
    Next c
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it right up, you truly just made my night!

Comment: Wonderful. If your problem is solved, to help everyone out, check the tick mark next to the answer so everyone can see that it's solved. Thanks.